# Device for testing BLE that works with Windows

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm looking for a recommendation for a device for testing BLE devices with Windows.  The Windows API itself seems really flaky, and doesn't give much debug information, so I'm thinking a standalone device, probably that plugs in over USB and skips the Windows BLE stack altogether is the way to go. What I'm looking for would:

- Be able to connect to a GattServer and do all the typical operations ( read, notify, etc )

Nice to haves:

- Give debug information about the connection state
- Trace packets
- Have some kind of automation hook, that is, COM, CLI, etc so that the data read from a characteristic could be dumped into Python etc

Anyone have any products they would recommend?

Comment: Take a look on one of their development board: www.nordicsemi.com

Comment: Or take a look on how to enable Bluetooth logging on Windows:https://github.com/Microsoft/busiotools/tree/master/bluetooth/tracing

Comment: You can use Zadig for any USB Bluetooth dongle to bypass the Bluetooth stack.